# Setup aws dynamodb with moodle framework php

Tags: php, amazon-dynamodb, moodle

I am implementing an application with moodle framework of php. To store session we are using `aws DynamoDb`.

The issue is, after adding `aws DyanamoDb` configuration, moodle is not creating a session file.

Please provide your solutions.

Comment: Hope this helps https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/scalable-session-handling-in-php-using-amazon-dynamodb/